# Why does close(gcf) retain a graphical handle in the workspace?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Say I plot some data as in

```
h = figure; plot(1:10);
```

This creates both a new window and an object in the workspace (`h`). Now if I close this window (mouse or command line)

```
close(h);
```

it does close the window but `h` is still in the workspace. `get(h)` returns

> Invalid or deleted object.

Why is that? I don't get the rationale of keeping an object that is a handle to a deleted figure you can do nothing with.

Comment: close(h) deletes the figure identified by h but not the object in itself. So you can just add `clear h` in order to delete an object.

Comment: Indeed - 2 calls for a single goal is weird though!

Comment: That's not exactly a single goal. That's two differents things. But you can create a small function if you really want an unique function.

Comment: `close` works by invoking the figure's `CloseRequestFcn`, whose behavior can vary significantly. You may not end actually up closing the figure (say you have a confirmation dialog box and click 'Don't Close'), which would make the implicit deletion of the variable pretty hazardous.

Comment: @excaza what about `delete(h)`?